# Trying to make a script to parse a CSV file and send out an email to the parties responsible for certificate renewals

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-3.0

As the title states I am trying to automate our certificate renewals in our organization. Right now this is all tracked in an Excel spreadsheet. Right now I have the script sending one email out to our team saying what is expiring. What I want to do is have it send out to each individual team with their certs that are expiring. The script I have currently is below:

```
Import-Csv -path D:\Scripts\Get-ExpiringCertificates\Certificates.csv |
    Where-Object {$_.Status -like "Expires*"} |
    Export-Csv D:\Scripts\Get-ExpiringCertificates\ExpiringCerts.csv
Send-MailMessage -From "NoReply@edmc.edu" -To _cssaadmessaging@edmc.edu -Subject "Expiring Certs" -SmtpServer "mailint.edmc.edu" -Attachments D:\Scripts\Get-ExpiringCertificates\ExpiringCerts.csv -Body "Please see attachment for the list of Certificates Expiring within the next 90 days."
```

I know that this is more than likely going to need to have an if statement for each responsible party.

An example of the CSV being used:

[image: CSV screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Instead of exporting the imported CSV data back to a file group the expiring certificates by responsible party, look up their mail address, then send the grouped information to the responsible team.

```
Import-Csv -path D:\Scripts\Get-ExpiringCertificates\Certificates.csv |
    Where-Object {$_.Status -like "Expires*"} |
    Group-Object 'Responsible Party' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $responsibleParty = $_.Name
        $recipient = ...    # look up mail address for $responsibleParty
        $data = $_.Group | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType
        Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -Body $data ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The code works for me in jenkins pipeline:

```
def stdout = powershell(returnStdout: true, script: '''
    Import-Csv -path C:/Users/VRD3KOR/.jenkins/workspace/Demo/list-merged-branches.csv |
    Where-Object {$_.Branchname -like "*"} |
    Group-Object 'last commiter email' |
    ForEach-Object {
        $lastCommiterEmail = $_.Name
        $recipient = $lastCommiterEmail   
        $data = $_.Group | ConvertTo-Csv -NoType
        $Subject = 'Warning: Deletion of merged branches'
        $From = 'abc@gmail.com'
        Send-MailMessage -To $recipient -From $From -Body ($data | Out-String) -Subject $Subject -SMTPserver "xxx.xxx.xx.x"
    }
''')
```